# Jquery: on filtering list(working), how to: make case insensitive, count number of keywords selected for each LI, and

Tags: javascript, jquery, filter, keyword, case-insensitive

http://jsfiddle.net/nicktheandroid/ape5U/

There's 2 or 3 things I need help with, if you can help me/guide me in the right direction on any of them, that would be great.

1) make script case-insensitive

2) When typing `'holy'` it will show **'angels, jesus, holy spirit'**, when adding the word `'spirit'` it will only show **'holy spirit'**. I want it to still show **'angels, jesus, holy spirit'** but to have the pink number next to each of those list items change to reflect how many keywords they each have that match one or more of the keywords you typed. So if i type `'holy spirit'` then I want it to show the **'angels, jesus, holy spirit'** list items, because they all have the keywords `'holy'`, so each list item's pink number should read **1**, but **'angels'** and **'holy spirit'** also contain the hidden keyword `'spirit'`, so their pink numbers should increase by **1** each.

- angels 2
- jesus 1
- holy spirit 2

now if I add `'archangel'` to `'holy spirit'` so i have `'holy spirit archangel'` typed in, then the `'angels'` list item's pink number should increase to 3, because it contains 3 of the keywords i've typed in, making it the most accurate one.

right now the pink numbers don't do anything, and it filters down and only shows the list items with the EXACT keywords. I need to correct these things, any help is MUCH appreciated. I've spent hours and hours on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you always store the tags as lowercase, then just convert all typed entries to lowercase before you use the split.  Additionally, you are presently matching against the text, not the tag list.

The way you have your matches test done, is like an & - AND, if you want it to be an | - OR then start false and switch to true when a positive match, rather than vice versa.

As for the counting, set all values to `0` at the commencement of a new scan, then when a tag is detected in the comparison loop, increment the value in that tag.

**Updated Demonstration:** http://jsfiddle.net/ape5U/22/

Comment: awesome man you helped me out a lot. Right now, it doesn't start filtering until `> 2` characters have been typed. If I type a word, then put a space and put a `g` or another single letter, it will add more list items to what's displayed because multiple list items have a `g` in them. Would you know how to address this situation or would you suggest anything? I don't want to take up too much of your time, thought it was worth a try though. i'm not sure how to handle this.

Comment: @android nick: If you only want whole words to match, then rather than using `$this.text().indexOf(a_filter)` to check for a match, you could use `$this.text().match("/\b" + a_filter + "\b/")` (or something near that) the `\b` means *word boundary* in a regex.

Comment: I did have this right there: `$(this).text().search(new RegExp(filter, "i")) < 0` but after many modifications, it doesn't work there anymore. tried what you suggested in your last comment, but it didn't work, hmmm... any ideas?

Comment: @android nick: Try creating a regexp, with the contents of the `.match()` I mentioned above `var re = new RegExp("\b" + a_filter + "\b")`, and then use the `re.test($this.text())` test function instead.  See if that works.

Comment: I tried what I thought you were saying, but what I tried didn't work. 
http://jsfiddle.net/nicktheandroid/ape5U/23/

Comment: @android.nick: There were two issues, firstly you were creating the RegExp outside of the loop, though the value of `a_filter` was only valid inside the loop, and therefore has to be set on each pass, and secondly the `"\b"` needed escaping to preserve the slash `"\\b"`.  See: http://jsfiddle.net/ape5U/26/

Comment: ah i'm a noob, but i'm in the homestretch of being done with this script that's cost me all too much time. if you're bored anytime soon(a continuation of my homestretch noobness): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5886432/jquery-javascript-have-a-filtering-listworks-need-help-keeping-all-lis-visib

Answer (score 0):

1. `var filter = $(this).val().toLowerCase()`

Make the value of the filter lower case and ensure all tags are lower case.