# Jquery javascript: have a filtering list(works), need help keeping all LI's visible when there's no matches

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, filter, match

http://jsfiddle.net/nicktheandroid/ape5U/34/

Type `hol` into the textbox on the fiddle example. you'll see that all the LI's have the class `hidden`, making them hidden. now if you make what you had in the textbox into the word `holy`, you'll see that you all the sudden have 3 matches.

I need it to show all LI's(categories) if there's no matches, instead of hiding all of them, ive been trying to figure this out for hours and cannot, when I change one thing it breaks another. grr.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add a condition at the end of your `if (length > 2)` statement, so you have:

```
if (length > 2) {   
   ...
   if(count == 0) $('.filtered li').removeClass("hidden"); //Add this line!
}else{
  ...
}
...
```

I tested and works ok. Hope this helps. Cheers

Comment: Preferably with braces, can't abide that no-brace-if style!